# Does fiber product preserve limits?

Tags: category-theory

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a category in which every fiber product exists.
Let $S' \rightarrow S$ be a morphism in $\mathcal{C}$.
Let $(\mathcal{C}\downarrow S)$ and $(\mathcal{C}\downarrow S')$ be [the slice categories](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_category#Definition). 
Let $F\colon (\mathcal{C}\downarrow S) \rightarrow (\mathcal{C}\downarrow S')$ be the functor defined by $F(X) =  X\times_S S'$.
Does $F$ preserve limits?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. In fact, $(-) \times_S S'$ preserves limits because it is the right adjoint of the functor that takes an object $X \to S'$ in $(\mathcal{C} \downarrow S')$ to the object $X \to S' \to S$ in $(\mathcal{C} \downarrow S)$.

Comment: I understand how you and Makoto Kato are definng F, but I have a question: is your notation really correct? The way you write it $(-) \times_S S'$ appears to be a functor in $\mathcal{C}$ and not on the slice, and can be misleading, as shown below in Augusti Roig question/comment

Comment: How could it possibly be a functor on $\mathcal{C}$? There is no chance of confusion.

Comment: The source of my puzzlement is this: $F$ is a functor on a slice cat, whose objects are really morphisms $f$ in $\mathcal{C}$. So - by writing the functor $F$ in that way - you end up with expressions like $f \times_S S'$ where you have a fiber product between a morphism $f$ and an object $S'$. I wonder : is this standard notation? if yes, where?

Comment: The notation we use is completely standard in algebraic geometry, for example, and fairly common elsewhere. It is an accepted abuse of notation.

Comment: Thank you. Could you please suggest an algebraic geometry text where these functors/arguments are used?

Comment: I don't really know what you're asking. This argument can be found in various category theory textbooks – certainly in Awodey (Ch. 9).

Comment: Indeed it is in Awodey's text, but I was under the impression that this functor F is used in algebraic geometry. So I am asking for an algebraic geometry text, if it is possible. Or, more in general, a good introductory text on algebraic geometry which uses categorical language

Comment: This functor is used whereever Grothendieck's relative point of view is fruitful: algebraic geometry is just one of them. There is literally no algebraic geometry content to this question or its answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and another explanation: your functor, being itself a limit, commutes with limits.

Comment: True, but _this_ functor is not a limit. The functor $(\mathcal{C} \downarrow S) \times (\mathcal{C} \downarrow S) \to (\mathcal{C} \downarrow S)$ that sends $(X \to S, Y \to S)$ to $X \times_S Y$ _is_, and it is right adjoint to the diagonal functor $\Delta : (\mathcal{C} \downarrow S) \to (\mathcal{C} \downarrow S) \times (\mathcal{C} \downarrow S)$.